# java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: 10 char of CLOB data cannot be read

Tags: java, oracle

I'm trying to save an xml file to data base, but when i try to set CLOB for CallableStatement i get this exception:

```
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: 10 char of CLOB data cannot be read
```

When I look through file in Notepad++ with all symbols shown I don't see any special characters. Database's encoding is AL32UTF8. How can i find these 10 characters that cannot be read? It's definitely not 10-th character as one can think because 10-th character in file is "s". First string:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

Code snippet:

```
CallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall("{ call scenario.add(?,?,?,?,?) }");
cs.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER);
cs.setLong(2, cfg.getScenarioId());
cs.setString(3, cfg.getType());
cs.setClob(4, new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8"), (int) file.length());
cs.setString(5, cfg.getFileName());
```

Application crashes on setClob (the same happens if use setCharacterStream()).

Comment: Is the file actually UTF-8, or might it have some ISO-8859-1 characters - even ones that render, maybe a currency symbol - that can't be converted nicely? Sounds like it might be a character-encoding problem, anyway.

Comment: Yes, it's actually UTF-8. Actually i've found a problem - it's 2 words in russian, both have 5 letters. But now i don't understand why do they cause a problem. I save the file in UTF-8, if i try to read it with another encoding i get a mess instead of these 2 words, in UTF-8 it is everything OK. So they are UTF-8, but CLOB doesn't want to read them. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i've found the solution. I still don't understand what is wrong with CLOB but all data is perfectly saved as object. I used this function to get file contents:

```
private String getContent(File file) throws IOException {
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    IOUtils.copy(new FileInputStream(file), writer, "UTF-8");
    String result = writer.toString();
    return result;
}
```

and then just saved result string as object:

```
CallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall("{ call scenario.add(?,?,?,?,?) }");
cs.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER);
cs.setLong(2, cfg.getScenarioId());
cs.setString(3, cfg.getType());
String fileContent = getContent(file);
cs.setObject(4, fileContent);
cs.setString(5, cfg.getFileName());
```

And it works!